# How should I use React to set a random background based on element id for multiple elements?

Tags: reactjs, random, swiper.js

So I have a **Swiper** installed in my React App.
My Swiper has **n** slides. For each of **n** slides I have the set of **m** images to set as a background.
On each onload event I want the React App to randomly choose the background for each slide based on its id.

Before I went to react, I've written the procedure I want in usual JS (I put it below and it worked somehow, but this one is not the last version so I am not sure, sorry, but nevermind).

`

```
function ChooseBG() {
// counts the number of slides in swiper
    let countSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide').length;
     // preset array for number of fotos for each slide to choose from written in order of slide number
    const CaseFotos = [2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 18, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5, 19];
    
for (let i=1; i <= countSlides; i++) {
    let randomCaseNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (CaseFotos[i-1]));
    let randomFotoLink = "url('../media/casual/selected/cas-" + i +"-" + randomCaseNumber +".jpg')";
    return document.getElementById("case"+i).style.backgroundImage = randomFotoLink; 
};
};
```

`

Everything worked bad with some lags and I've decided to move to React.
Below is my temporal code for swiper in react app.
So in my imagination and my interpretation of **how should it better make in React** I should write the function analogous to one above which would generate the random background by id of the element asking the function to return the result. HOW?

`

```
import React from 'react';
import MainSlide from './MainSwiperSlide';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

//the index of imported images named by the template case0v0 case0v1 case1v0 case1v1 etc 
import SwiperImagesStack from './media/swiper-images/SwiperImagesIndex';
 
export default function MainSwiper() {

MyStyleFunctionForID() { }

return (
  
      <Swiper
        speed={900}
        slidesPerView={1}
        loop
        className="MainSwiper"
        >
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' id="case0" >
              <MainSlide SlideText="SOME TEXT CASE 0" style={{MyStyleFunctionForID()}}/>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' id="case1" style={{MyStyleFunctionForID()}}>
              <MainSlide SlideText="SOME ANOTHER TEXT CASE 1" />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' id="case2" style={{MyStyleFunctionForID()}}>
              <MainSlide SlideText="SOME ANOTHER TEXT CASE 2" />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' id="case3" style={{MyStyleFunctionForID()}}>
              <MainSlide SlideText="SOME ANOTHER TEXT CASE 3" />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide' id="case4" style={{MyStyleFunctionForID()}}>
              <MainSlide SlideText="SOME ANOTHER TEXT CASE 4" />
          </SwiperSlide>
         
      </Swiper>

  
  );
}
```

`

Thanks in advance!!!

I'm quite young in programming and in react especially, I googled for a night long, I've tried refs, i've tried hooks, but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Well, with a help from my friend Vova I probably decided the issue (it works, however, I would like to make the code better!)

So, first I create the array of arrays of the images in a separate js file

```
import cas0V0 from './cas-0-0.jpg';
import cas0V1 from './cas-0-1.jpg';
import cas0V2 from './cas-0-2.jpg';
import cas0V3 from './cas-0-3.jpg';
import cas0V4 from './cas-0-4.jpg';
import cas0V5 from './cas-0-5.jpg';
import cas1V0 from './cas-1-0.jpg';
import cas1V1 from './cas-1-1.jpg';
import cas2V0 from './cas-2-0.jpg';
import cas2V1 from './cas-2-1.jpg';
import cas2V2 from './cas-2-2.jpg';
const s0 = [cas0V0, cas0V1, cas0V2, cas0V3, cas0V4, cas0V5];
const s1 = [cas1V0, cas1V1];
const s2 = [cas2V0, cas2V1, cas2V2];

const SwiperImagesStack = [
  s0, s1, s2]
;

export default SwiperImagesStack;
```

And here what I write in react app:

```
export default function MainSwiper() {
  const numberOfSlide = 3
  const CaseFotos = Array.from(Array(numberOfSlide).keys());
  const mybg = (index) => ({ backgroundImage: `url('${SwiperImagesStack[index][Math.floor(Math.random() * (SwiperImagesStack[index].length))]}')` })    

  return (
    <Swiper
      modules={[Navigation, EffectFade]}
      navigation
      speed={900}
      slidesPerView={1}
      loop
      className="MainSwiper">
        {CaseFotos.map((index) => 
          <SwiperSlide className='SwiperSlide'  id={`case${index}`} style={mybg(index)} >
            <MainSlide SlideText={`SOME TEXT CASE' ${index}`} key={'key1'} />
          </SwiperSlide>)}
    </Swiper> 
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue now is that i have 120 fotos and probably will have more later. 
So it's kind a stupid to write import 120 times and also it should probably decrease the site loading. So I'll try now to write the function which could generate the link to import. And here I am afraid of timing - how to ask Swiper to wait until the import will be done...